# Is it permitted to do remote/freelance work for a non-German company while on a work visa in Germany?

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit

If I was able to get a work permit through a part time ESL teaching job, would I be allowed to keep my 25 hour a week remote job through a US company?

Does Germany allow for those on work permits to do freelance work on the side?

I speak German, have a Bachelor's in Journalism and German, have a TEFL certification and I have family that lives in Germany.

I consider it a second home and want to move there, but I don't want to give up my current remote job.

Comment: Are you already in Germany on a work visa?

Comment: The following answer might be relevant for you (but still does not answer your question): https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/12888/13223

Answer (score -1):

A work permit for freelance English teachers will legally ONLY permit you to teach English,  no side jobs.